How to override global Jest mock
I have defined a global mock in my setupJest file as follows...
jest.mock('@pathTo/aModule', () => ({
  moduleFunction: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() =>
    jest.fn().mockImplementation((_string) => ({
      valid: true,
      userId: 'admin_test_user',
      error: null,
    })),
  ),
}));

In my test file, I am attempting to override this mock as follows...
import { moduleFunction } from '@pathTo/aModule';

  it('GET returns 403', async () => {
    (moduleFunction as jest.Mock).mockImplementation(() =>
     jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
       valid: true,
       userId: 'another_user',
       error: null,
      })),
    );

    const response = await supertest(app)
      .get(`route`)
      .set('Authorization', 'Token')
      .expect(403);

    expect(response.body.message).toBe('Insufficient permissions.');
  });

However the mock remains as it was, I cannot seem to override it. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
